# How to run node js even on server restart

Tags: node.js, linux, server, centos

I built a Nodejs project and now it runs smoothly. 
I use `forever` service for running file in background but if server get restarted 
the daemon won't be started automatically and should be started manually.
I want to run the daemon even the server get rebooted

Comment: what OS are you using for your server?

Comment: @RaghavGarg I am using centos7

Comment: Have you tried forever, pm2, nodemon, ...?

Comment: You should integrate with `systemd`, it has many advantages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add the forever command in `.bash_profile` so that every time the server restart, your command will simply be also executed.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
forever start app.js # add this command to the file, or whatever command you are using.
source ~/.bash_profile # very important, else changes will not take effect
```

Next time, on your server restart, your command will also run, hence creating a daemon of your node script.

**Note:** This is maybe not the best solution, but the one I have got.

## Update

As @dlmeetei, suggested, you can also start your nodejs app like a service so that we can use the features given by a linux service.

First create a file in `/etc/systemd/system`, like:

```
touch /etc/systemd/system/[your-app-name].service
nano /etc/systemd/system/[your-app-name].service
```

Then, add and edit the following script according to your relevance.

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Example Server
#Requires=After=mysql.service # Requires the mysql service to run first

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /opt/nodeserver/server.js
# Required on some systems
# WorkingDirectory=/opt/nodeserver
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if node service crashes
RestartSec=10
# Output to syslog
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-example
#User=<alternate user>
#Group=<alternate group>
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=1337

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service, it will marks the service for starting up on boot.

```
systemctl enable [your-app-name].service
```

Manage the service

```
systemctl start [your-app-name].service
systemctl stop [your-app-name].service
systemctl status [your-app-name].service # ensure your app is running
systemctl restart [your-app-name].service
```

**Reference:** https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/nodejs-service-with-systemd/

Thanks @dlmeetei for sharing the link.

Comment: This will only start your server when you start `bash`. Better to integrate with `systemd` or write init.d script based on lsb.

Comment: @dlmeetei, I am not too good in Unix system. are you suggesting to make a service of it? If not, can you please share, how it can be done with systemd or init.d, whichever is better?

Comment: May be this will help https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/nodejs-service-with-systemd/

Comment: @dlmeetei, this seems like a nice approach, I haven't really thought of starting a node app like a service. Thanks for sharing the link.